# Stop Yahoo Messenger (ymgr_tray.exe) from auto-starting during boot

Tags: boot, yahoo-messenger

I am using Yahoo Messenger version 9 on Windows Xp home and disabled auto starting during bootup using msconfig(unchecked the program  to stop starting up). But I still find the ymgr_tray.exe process running everytime during bootup. How do I stop it from auto starting during boot? This happens with realplay.exe as well !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you remove the Yahoo Messenger program from the msconfig start up list, it rewrites itself into the startup list again. There’s a way to get rid of this. Here’s how:

- Start Yahoo Messenger
- Sign in with your Yahoo ID In the menu bar
- Click Messenger and then go to Preferences
- In the window that appears, uncheck ‘Automatically startup Yahoo Messenger’
- Press ‘Apply’, ‘OK’

Source: http://blog.shankarganesh.com/2007/10/29/stop-yahoo-messenger-from-starting-up-when-windows-starts/